# "the module didn't load at the default load address." - does it make sense nowadays?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

"the module didn't load at the default load address." - does this warning message makes sense nowadays from a performance point of view.

back to 10-20 years ago there was probably some performance hit to re-map func addresses in case if a module is loaded to a base address other than preferred, but now it is just a few extra milliseconds if not less.

Am I right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

From a performance standpoint, probably not, but it makes a difference in memory usage.  [Windows DLLs aren't position-independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_independent_code#Windows_DLLs) so when a DLL has to be relocated to a different address, the linker has to actually modify its machine code.  That means it can't be shared with other processes; each program gets its own separate copy of the code.  On the other hand, when a DLL loads at its preferred address in multiple programs, the same (unmodified) pages can be shared among them, which saves memory.

Comment: And how can I force the module to load from default address?